# Cannot load doctrine:config , services.xml

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

I am trying to build an eventlistener for my project and followed the instruction of this guide: [How to register eventlisteners](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) I edited my services.xml like in the tutorial , but i get this error message, when i want to test it:

```
InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "doctrine:config" (in /var/www/symfony/src/Acme/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/services.xml). Looked for namespace "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/doctrine", found none
```

My services.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:doctrine="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/doctrine"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">



    <doctrine:config>
        <doctrine:dbal default-connection="default">
            <doctrine:connection driver="pdo_sqlite" memory="true" />
        </doctrine:dbal>
    </doctrine:config>

    <services>
        <service id="my.listener" class="Acme\AppBundle\EventListener\Confirmer">
            <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="preUpdate" />
        </service>

    </services> 

</container>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: do i have to change any config to use a services.yml ?

Comment: The Symfony [guide](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) displays each configuration sections in three languages: YAML, XML and PHP. You can switch between them using the tabs at the top. YAML is the default.

Comment: YAML isn't the default for service configuration, almost all of the widely used bundles out there use XMl ... for a good reason - XML provides better autocompletion and validation options. The IDE integration for XML files can provide you easier coding than YAML especially with Emmet or ZenCoding involved.

Comment: The symfony standard edition already comes with a preconfigured doctrine connection. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the doctrine configuration in your service config.

The connection driver is being configured inside `app/config/config.yml`.
The listener configuration looks good though - just remove the `doctrine:config` stuff.

Have a look at the [doctrine configuration reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html).

Symfony will automatically use the default connection for your listener/subscriber if you don't specify one using the `connection`option. The documentation is a bit confusing here but the doctrine connection is just there to show how to use a different connection.